# anyojs: how to embed controls in list items?

Tags: enyo

I'm completely new to enyo and trying to learn. So, i've decided to create a simple configuration app for my server-side project.

I am trying to crate something like this:

```
group1    [on]/ off  |  option1    <select_box_selected_opt1>
group2     on /[off] |  option2    <select_box_selected_opt2>
group3    [on]/ off  >  option3    <select_box_selected_opt3>
                     |  option4    <select_box_selected_opt4>
                     |  option5    <select_box_selected_opt5>
                     |  option6    <select_box_selected_opt6>
```

So these are two lists with items like

```
{name:"option_name"}, {name:"switch", kind:"onyx.ToggleButton"}
```

or a picker in right one.

Problem is togglers, checkboxes and pickers are not working. They behave strange: togglers do not change their visual state after first click and pickers do not display options and their buttons freze in "pressed" state. The oncnahge events happen, but in strange order.

No errors or warnings in console.

Maybe, i'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation here:  https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Lists

`List` uses a flyweight pattern so the controls aren't 'live' without a little help.  You probably want a `Repeater` instead.